# How can I access the browser logs and store them in a variable programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I need to capture the INFO level logs and store them in a variable

[image]

console command to fetch all INFO level loggings would be a great help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read from Chrome's console in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Overwrite `console.log` with your own implementation that saves the argument(s) as needed, then calls the original `console.log`:

```js
const logArgs = [];
const origConsoleLog = console.log;
console.log = (...args) => {
  logArgs.push(args);
  origConsoleLog(...args);
};

console.log('foo');
console.log('bar');
console.dir(logArgs);
```