# Display console log results inside html element

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

- it's possible to catch the browser console log and display it in html element i know this question is asked many times before but what i found is just they are overwrite `console.log()` function like
  `console.log = (masg) => elem.innerHTML = msg` i think that it's nothing it's just add new function with the same name of `console.log` but i need to get the value of console after it's gone through it and displayed the error or objects, array, etc.. result
- my question is how can i get all the log of the console and display it in html element not just errors but also testing results can anyone help me

Comment: Why do you not want to overwrite `console.log`?

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the `console.log` i just need to get the testing results and error of the `console`

Comment: "it's possible to catch the browser console log and display it in html element ..." is an assertion which is not true. The answer to your question lies more with implementing the equivalent of `console` in script. My toolbox version of that is unpublished, but you might try searching for "remote console".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
console.log = function(...logs) 
{
    var text = logs.map(e=> JSON.stringify(e)).join(' ');
    elem.innerHTML = text;
}
```

**Beware of circular structures. It brings error.**

Extended variant

```
var consoleLog = console.log;
console.log = console.error = console.warn = function(...logs) {

    var text = logs.map(e=> {
                   if (e instanceof Error) return `Error: ${e.message}`;
                   else if (Array.isArray(e)) return `<ul>${e.map(l => `<li>${l}</li>`).join('')}</ul>`;
                   // other stuff
                   else {
                       try {
                           return JSON.stringify(e);
                       } catch(e) {
                           consoleLog(...logs);
                           return `${e.message}<br/>See the console for details`;
                       }
                   }
               }).join(' ');

    elem.innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: How you are understand my question i don't want to overwrite the ` console log ` i want to get all the testing results and errors from the Browser `console.log` and display it inside html element

Comment: Can you help me

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript/19846113