# can I download client logs as a text file in react app?

Tags: reactjs

It would be possible to download my client logs as file (let's say my console.log logs) using a button in a react app?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not have a way to do this, therefore react does not. See this SO entry for more information: [Stack Overflow Article How to Read from Chromes Console in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript). The only thing you can do, according to the linked article, is to setup a hook to log it elsewhere whenever you log. This may be helpful, and there are examples in the log below.