# How to send Send TypeErros in Chrome console to Alert

Tags: javascript, html, dom, try-catch

Consider a script file with

```
 let something = undefined;
 let undefined = something.test;
```

This will throw in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'test')
```

How can that error be sent to an Alert to the user, rather than accessing the console?

The two approaches below have been tried with no success - Also wrapping the assignment into a try catch throw.

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber, column, errorObj) {
    alert(
      `Error: ` +
        errorMsg +
        ` Script: ` +
        url +
        ` Line: ` +
        lineNumber +
        ` Column: ` +
        column +
        ` StackTrace: ` +
        errorObj
    );
  };

window.addEventListener("error", handleError, true);

function handleError(evt) {
    if (evt.message) { // Chrome sometimes provides this
      alert("error: "+evt.message +" at linenumber: "+evt.lineno+" of file: "+evt.filename);
    } else {
      alert("error: "+evt.type+" from element: "+(evt.srcElement || evt.target));
    }
}
```

I though this might be a load order issue, but the function is in a separate script file that is loaded before the file with the incorrect assignment.

Comment: maybe some answers in here would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript

Comment: Some interesting thoughts, however nothing seems to want to trigger on TypeError. It's logged in the console, but can't seem to be captured anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You tried try catch? This is working for me.

```
try {
  let c = undefined.test;
} catch(error) {
  alert(error);
}
```

Ok I was able to get the window.onerror to work by running it on a localhost server

In one javascript file I defined the following.

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg) {
    alert(errorMsg);
};
```

In another I caused the error with:

```
let c = undefined.test;
```

I believe the reason is CORS issue see:

[When an error occurs in a script, loaded from a different origin, the details of the error are not reported to prevent leaking information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror)

Running this code on a local python http server shows the full error message in the alert.
Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It could work independently I suppose - However I was hoping that the global window object could handle this, rather than having to have try catch blocks everywhere...

Comment: Hey I think I found a solution lmk if it works for you

Comment: "....Instead the error reported is "Script error."" - But here, we're getting TypeError in the browser, and nothing reported to the error handler function :/

Comment: Ok. Can you share more information about where you are defining the onerror function and where you are creating the error?

Comment: The two scrips are sequentially required in the head of the document. 

<src=errorFunction.js>
<src=assignment.js>

So load order is correct 

The error is generated in assigment.js