# Eval Javascript string and store stdout

Tags: javascript

I get Js as a string and I need to execute that script and compare the output to something. I'm using `eval()` here but can be anything. It runs on client side in the browser.

Is there any way to do this without changing the string `a`?

```
let a = "console.log(\"a\")";
eval(a);
let stdout = ???
```

Comment: Never use eval(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!

Comment: "Is there any way to do this without changing the string a?" why do you need to change that?

Comment: `"Without changing a"`, I guess you want to keep `console.log` in the string, but will have to change the actual `console.log` function. But that may affect unrelated parts of the program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read from Chrome's console in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript)

Comment: The "output" (i.e return value) of the script in the string is `undefined`. That's what `eval()` will return to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

- `bind()`
- `call()`

you can extend `console.log` so that an additonal, separate live record is kept of all the log entries.

In the working example below, you can see that every time something is logged to the `console`, it is simultaneously added to the `console.stdout` array.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
console.stdout = [];
console.logInclStdout = console.log.bind(console);

console.log = (logEntry) => {
    console.stdout.push(logEntry);
    console.logInclStdout.call(console, logEntry);
}


let a = "console.log('a')";
let b = "console.log('b')";
let c = "console.log('c')";

let saferFasterEval = (input) => Function(`"use strict"; ${input}`)();

saferFasterEval(a);
saferFasterEval(b);
saferFasterEval(c);

// When you want to see what has been logged via console.log
console.info(console.stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save the messages executed with `console.log` inside the `eval` one way would be to overwrite the `console.log` however I would not recommend overwriting or using `eval`

```
// Store the original console.log function
const temp = console.log;

// Create an array to hold the commands
const cmds = []

// Overwrite the console.log to store the logs
console.log = (msg) => { cmds.push(msg) };

// Run A
let a = "console.log(\"a\")";
eval(a);

// Run B
let b = "console.log(\"b\")";
eval(b);

// Run C
let c = "console.log(\"c\")";
eval(c);

// Get the logs; You can use `cmd.join('\n')` to get the messages as a string
let stdout = cmds;

// Revert to orignal console.log
console.log = temp
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/x0w2q4Le/4/

Answer (score 0):

Eval returns the output if you pass it to a variable:

```js
let a = `
    let test = 10
    test++
    test
`
let stdout = eval(a)
```

Just put the value you want to return at the end