# Angular console.log output to html

Tags: javascript, html, angular, console.log

I created a web js editor with angular and ngx-ace-wrapper lib. Now I trying to output a console.log to HTML div element. But I do not found any solution. How I can get console output or mirror to my DOM.

I tried to override conmsole.log and console.error

"preview" is a variable where I store my output as innerHTML

```
console.log = message => {
  this.preview += message + "\n";

    _log(message);

}
console.error = error => {
  this.preview += JSON.stringify(error) + "\n";
  _error(error);
}
```

Comment: why would you want to do that? This seems like a major red flag to me. Can you provide some more information on why you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: So trying to output console log to my DOM but with angular.
As sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript
I created Javascript web Editor and I have "output" element where I need to mirror console log with errors

Answer (score 0):

To get the HTML to render you can save the HTML in some variable and use the `innerHtml` attribute and pass in your html

`<div [innerHTML]="myHtml"></div>`

Comment: The question is how to get a console from the browser and mirror to HTML as result\output