# VSCode extension dump console constent

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, console.log

I am writing an extension for Visual Studio Code and I would like to receive logs from users if they click a button.

Currently I made a wrapper around console.log like this :

```js
import * as path from 'path';

export const logger = (baseName: string) => {

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "dev") return () => { };

    baseName = path.basename(baseName).toUpperCase().toString()
    return (...params: any[]) => {

        // 1. Convert args to a normal array
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(params);

        // 2. Prepend log prefix log string
        args.unshift(baseName + ": ");

        console.log.apply(console, args);
    }
};
```

It works fine for output that I create myself, so I could store it in some array. However this doesn't account for error, which is very important to debug and reproduce the issue.

I've checked solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript), but due to the extension sandboxing and/or the fact this is nodejs (so window is not defined here) I was not able to use them.