# Injecting JavaScript from chrome extenstion not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

For developing a Chrome extension, I am injecting JS code from content_scripts into the site. `content_scripts.js` code looks like:

```
const mainDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
mainDiv.innerHTML = 
    `<div id="innerDiv">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <script>
        alert("First");
        function doSome(){
            alert("Hi");
        }
    </script>`;
    
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', mainDiv);

setTimeout(() => {  
    alert("Test"); 
    doSome();    
}, 5000);
```

In the website `HTML` tag and `JavaScript` were injected.

[image]

`doSome()` function and `alert("First")` not executing. But this `alert("Test")` is executing.

The browser console gives an error message `content_scripts.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: doSome is not defined`.

[image]

I've also tried it in a different way. `content_scripts.js` code looks like:

```
const mainDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
mainDiv.innerHTML = 
    `<div id="innerDiv">Lorem ipsum</div>`;
    
document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', mainDiv);

document.getElementById('innerDiv').innerHTML = 
    `<script>
        alert("Second");
        function doAnother(){
            alert("Hello");
        }
    </script>`;

setTimeout(() => {
    alert("Best");       
    doAnother();    
}, 5000);
```

In the website `HTML` tag and `JavaScript` were injected.

[image]

`doAnother()` function and `alert("Second")` not executing. But this `alert("Best")` is executing.

The browser console gives an error message `content_scripts.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: doAnother is not defined`.

[image]

It was flagged as a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml). I also tried `eval()` but no luck.

What can I do to execute `alert("First")` or `alert("Second")` or `doSome()` or `doAnother()`?

Comment: ManifestV3 extensions can't inject literal code in the content script, see the workarounds in [this answer](/a/9517879). However, note that such code cannot be called from content script due to isolation as explained in the answer I've linked. If you need further assistance please clarify the goal of your extension and why you inject the code.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. 

I need all data of console.log. This solution works fine. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript/19846113#19846113

I get the console.log data only which are in `content_scripts.js`.  

Suppose when the extension runs above of example.com I need the console.log of the example.com