# How to read file from chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have popup.html where popup.js is invoked when popup is loaded by clicking on browser action. There I'm programmatically injecting content scripts with `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`. I need to append one element to page's body. How can I insert HTML code from different .html file within extension, because it's much easier to maintain the code like that. I was thinking of accessing it within popup.js (is there some API call for that?) and then within `code` attribute to insert content script code with string of retrieved HTML code.

I saw some methods using `XMLHttpRequest` from content script, but is there to avoid that? I tried with `chrome.fileSystem`, but that's for chrome apps and not extensions.

Comment: I exactly said that I wouldn't like to use Ajax request with XMLHttpRequest. Isn't there a way to load another HTML from popup.js which is not a content script?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As a comment mentioned, it's just a question of making a GET request to `chrome.runtime.getURL("myfile.html")`, where `"myfile.html"` is the relative path (from the root of the extension) to the file that you want.

You can do that with raw XHR or, if you're using jQuery, using `$.ajax`.

To do it from a content script, you need to declare it in [`"web_accessible_resources"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

---

Since you don't want that, yes, there is another way (not available to content scripts).

You can obtain a read-only [HTML5 Filesystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) access to your extension's files with [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry):

```
chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(root) {
  root.getFile("myfile.html", {}, function(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        // contents are in this.result
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }, errorHandler);
  }, errorHandler);
});
```

As you can see, this is vastly more complicated than an XHR request. One would probably use this only if one wants to [list the files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26273405/934239).

Comment: What's confusing me is that - content scripts are the ones which are inserted in viewing page, but the other javascript file (such as running with extensions popup windows) aren't and they should have a way to access the other files within extension, isn't that so? Do those scripts also need to make ajax calls?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed your requirement late. I'm currently editing the answer.

Comment: Yea, true. This really is much more complicated. Thanks for these explanations.

Comment: do paths always start with `/crxfs/`?