# chrome extension - Fill the web form from the data from Excel

Tags: excel, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to fill the web form by bringing the data from excel in chrome extension?

i have an url with some numbers, example http://www.desipearl.com/tracker/544258/371/ASD-Collection-736151299754834/57/smp/

the number 544258 will keep an increased by one number, according the number change the article get changed

The above mentioned url is available in excel database,

i want to post the first url number 544258 then after some interval i want to post 544259 , this keeps on going on constant interval

Can we achieve the above mentioned function by chrome extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier to do this via python. I'd use the `openpyxl` module from python which is documented [here](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/). Then I'd go through each number in the spreadsheet and use the `requests` module to get the page using a GET request as documented [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

With a chrome extension you could do this. The general steps would be to [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858027/how-to-read-file-from-chrome-extension) the excel file. Then process it to get a list of numbers and then make a GET request using those numbers from chrome.

Comment: Dear Mr Saleh Hindi - thanks for your kind reply, will try the same , Mean time do you have some sample ?

Comment: You're welcome : ) Be sure to give me an upvote if you like my answer so I can enjoy the fake internet points haha