# How to get content of javascript files as variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have to develop a chrome extension for my thesis which does following analysis:

This extension should analyse the javascript files (.js) and webssembly files (.wasm) of visited webpages. For example i have to check if a javascript file contains a special string X. In somepages included files are on visited domain in somepages on another domain. Via security reasons maybe it would be diffucult to get content of these files. Is it possible to get content of these files as a variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read file from chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858027/how-to-read-file-from-chrome-extension)

Comment: i think this is not duplicate. because i want also read content of webassembly files

Comment: Once you read the file in a var, will that not be reading the content of the file?

Comment: You can use [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) to see what files the browser is loading and use AJAX to download the files you're interested in to do your check.

Comment: do you have maybe a sample usage for chrome.webRequest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get file contents with jquery

```
jQuery.get('http://localhost/filename.ext', function(data) {
    var jsFile = data;
});
```

Comment: i get following error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ***************** is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

Comment: This is a separate issue, hence a separate question ready resolved in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present. you are reading the URL of a different domain. Look at "Using CORS."

Comment: And is there any option to get the content via chrome sources? is there any special permission for chrome extensions to read content of loaded files?