# Writing to a text file in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

I am currently writing a string of text to the console for testing reasons, as below:

console.log JSON.stringify @classification

How do I write this to a text file in coffeescript?

Cheers

James

In node.js - and I want to write to a filename of my choosing - not a default log file.

Comment: Where is executed your script ? On a server ? In node.js ?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file) ?

Answer (score 5):

```
fs = require "fs"
fs.writeFile "classification.json", JSON.stringify(@classification), (error) ->
  console.error("Error writing file", error) if error
```

Comment: if "classification.json" does not work,
try:
path.resolve(__dirname, ".", "classification.json") 
(you'll need path = require "path")