# In chrome console how to copy the last 20 commands i have written to clipboard

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to copy all the commands i have written, or to give it some range. Or at least print them out together so i can copy them.

I was trying out jquery selectors in console, after half hour of dealing with very messy dom structure i finally got what i wanted now to transfer that i have to back in history and copy paste every single command. It'd be nice if could log all i have writen, or like last 30 commands etc.

I think it should be possible, as i have seen pretty other advanced abilities of chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer appears to address your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068090/1085891)

> 1. Enable [logging](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) from the command line using the flags:
>
>    > ```
>    > --enable-logging --v=1
>    > ```
>
>    This logs everything Chrome does internally, but it also logs all the
>      `console.log()` messages as well.  The log file is called
>      **`chrome_debug.log`** and is located in the [`User Data Directory`](http://dev.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).
> 2. Filter the log file you get for lines with '`CONSOLE(\d+)`'.

via [Save the console.log in Chrome to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file)

More here on logging. [The Chromium Projects: How to enable logging](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging)

Comment: I don't want to get all results of `console.log()` I want to save or preferably **copy** all commands i have written in console.

Comment: You could filter the output further with the commands you are interested in.