# Chrome Dev Tools - capture every line of code that's run

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I want to be able to type something into a textfield and after pressing 'Enter' capture every line of code that's run from that point to when the "operation" is complete.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on line #1 and step through your code?

Comment: Well, I could step through my code. I was wondering if I could somehow output a file or something that lists a sequence of everything that was run as result of that event.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies your question. Perhaps look into something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file

Comment: haha I just realized how idiotic my question sounded. Yes stepping through the code is a perfectly viable approach, I just want a neat file I could look through rather than step step step. I suppose it wouldn't really be a neat file - stepping is probably the best way.

Comment: Nope. That is a lot of data and most of it doesn't matter. What really matters most of the time is seen in stepping through. If that doesn't fix your problem, then you need to read the specification of related things being used to see how it should respond internally.