# Protractor - dont clear console logs after navigation

Tags: google-chrome, logging, browser, console, protractor

How to capture browser logs after a page navigation in an automation test?
The test:
Click button trigger writing to browser console + does page navigation.
In chrome, there is the option in the Dev Tools: Preserve log upon navigation

[Want to do that in protractor + chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6In8.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the browser logs are not preserved by default if you are using `browser.manage().logs().get('browser')` solution from this [FAQ section](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5fa86dc477b9502a046bac38179f5134e2dcd449/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-get-hold-of-the-browsers-console)? Thanks.

Comment: They are not. After page navigation the console clears

Comment: Another way is to save logs to file: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file

Answer (score 0):

```
var logmsg;

function aftereach(){
browser.manage().logs().get('browser').then(function (browserLogs) {
        browserLogs.forEach(function (log) {
            logmsg = logmsg + log;
        });
}
```

You can use global variable to preserve logs. Or you can also store it in text file, if you wish to know its code ask me.