# Chrome: redirect console.log to stdout

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, automated-tests, tap

I am investigating easy ways to reuse tests that output the [TAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol) format.

I want to be able to start Chrome from the command line and capture console.log output

If I have the following file called `index.html`

```
<script>
  console.log('beep boop!')
</script>
```

...can I then capture from the command line by doing something like this:

```
# start-crome --flag > out.txt
```

...and have out.txt contain "beep boop!"?

**EDIT:** Yes there are other questions that cover saving console.log to file manually. I want to pipe console log to stdout, so that debug information can be analysed in an automated unix setting

Comment: You can make non windows Chrome write to stderr with --enable-logging=stderr although you will get a lot of other messages as well

Comment: Yes- but you really get A LOT of random log output, that is impossible to parse. Plus its "incorrect" that normal log info should be directed to stderr instead of stdout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save the console.log in Chrome to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file)

Comment: @dloeda that is a question about saving console.log (something which is now fairly trivial to do manually). I want to pipe console log to stdout, so that debug information can be analysed in an automated unix setting

Comment: @fergie a solution to this problem could be to save console.log and pipe the information from this file with the command `tail -f chrome_debug.log | Analyzer`

Comment: @dloeda if there is a way to save the console.log to file programatically, then yes, that would work. "Save the console.log to file programatically" is the crux of the question.

Comment: @Fergie seems that lib [debugout](https://github.com/inorganik/debugout.js) do what you want, Can you add libraries?

Comment: @dloeda no- debugout does not redirect console.log to stdout

Comment: You would get lots of random output, but you could add a special tag to your output and then grep for it.