# How to save all console output in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, console.log

I'm saving Chrome's `console.log` output to a `chrome_debug.log` file using [the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file) `--enable-logging` key and it turns out that (whatever verbosity level is set) only first argument passed is stored in logs.

So, say, for this:

> console.log('AAAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBB', 'CCCCCC');

You'll get just something like:

> [68867:1295:0414/182234:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "AAAAAAAAA", source:  (2)

So, `BBBBBB` and `CCCCCC` won't be logged at all.

This is, well, frustrating. My question is - is there's a way to save **all** console.log output to a file.

**UPD:** please, keep in mind that this question is **not** duplicate of one which is linked here - in that question the very fact that only the first param is logged is not mentioned at all. The question is, once again, about how to log all params passed to `console.log`.

Comment: sorry for that, I'll remove the flag

Comment: @HaibaraAi actually thank you, this gave me a hint that I should edit question to make it clearer.