# Is it possible to save console logs to chrome_debug.log just from one extension

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-extension, console.log

I am trying to save some data about browser usage but locally. I enable logging with chrome start and I can find chrome_debug.log with all console text. I just need to save only messages from extension with ID bkdejfodnieiifpcgcmbgfdlibjhgcja or lines with my inserted keyword for example keyword is BANANA and log is something like that:

`[2928:6480:0628/163351:INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "BANANA;IMPORTANT;DATA;THAT;I;WANT", source: chrome-extension://bkdejfodnieiifpcgcmbgfdlibjhgcja/background.js (20)`

How can I edit what to save in chrome_debug.log, I find some thread where explain how to show only warn / debug / info but it is still many lines for me.
Maybe [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/base/logging.h) I can edit some script but I am not sure and don't want destroy it.

I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: Solution given in this SO post - [Save the console.log in Chrome to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file) might help.

Comment: Thanks! I saw this post but didn't understand "Filter the log file you get for lines with CONSOLE(\d+)" ,, where exactly should I write that command, because I dont want to select lines from chrome_debug.log but write there just what I need, nothing more nothing less.. is that possible?