# Collect output of log tab ( chromium developer tools)

Tags: python, shell, google-chrome

I am looking at an application running in Chrome (it is an Electron app), and I see that there are a lot of interesting info in the "console" tab of the developer tools in Chrome.

Is possible to collect these logs somehow? I did look for logs but I was not able to find any; I am on OSX. I did check also in tmp and they were not there either, so I am not even sure if it is possible to collect these logs at all. I can use either shell script or python.

To be clear, I can't go in Chrome, display the dev tools and save by hand the logs; I need to get the logs either from a file already on the system, or calling a command via console.

Answer (score 1):

[Save the console.log in Chrome to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file), might help, would allow you to save the console output to a file then write a python or shell script to parse the logs.

Comment: I am looking for a way that does not involve me to go in the UI, enable dev tools and save manually on a text. This is not practical if you are checking logs periodically