# Chrome --enable-logging flag not taking effect

Tags: google-chrome, logging

I'm trying to log my chrome console output to a file. I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file).

For some reason, the logfile only contains the internal chrome content, and *none* of my `console.log()` output.

I'm running the following command:

`chrome.exe "http://my.url.here" --enable-logging --v=1`

I'm on Windows 7. I've also tried using `--log-level=0`, it produces the same behavior without the histogram.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured this one out. Turns out you need to close *all* instances of chrome before running the command line. Even if they're separate tabs / processes.