# How do i print the Event Listener(Selenium) log generated in console to the notepad text file

Tags: java, selenium

I have done to print logs in the console but I have no idea how to print logs in a text file

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow:) You question is too general and should contains more details about the problem you are facing. But seems your question is a duplicate of [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creat a new instance of `FileWriter`,I will name it `fileWriter` , give it a target `File` where to write. Then use the `fileWriter.write()` to write into the file. When done, call `fileWriter.close()`, this will save the changes to the file.