# How to copy all 404 Error URL's from Console?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, console, http-status-code-404

For example I have a page and it loads images and other files and some images/files are not available in my directory and and as such the browser throws a 404 error when trying to retrieve these images/files.

As such, my dev console spits out these errors:

```
GET http://www.google.com/does_not_exist.jpg 404 (Not Found)
GET http://www.google.com/also_does_not_exist.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

I can copy one URL at a time but it's time consuming if there are 100 or more URLs.

How can I copy all the 404 URL's at once?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save the console.log in Chrome to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file)

Comment: Nope sorry that doesn't work perfectly. I just want to copy 404 error links nothing else.

Comment: Any solution guys?

Comment: How about saving all the log output to a file like explained in the other question and then filtering that file?

Comment: It will work but it gonna be so messy. Am gonna confuse myself which line of code have to be removed.

Comment: You could just use `grep 'GET.*404'` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks mate for the information. grep command will help me to achieve the similar result.