# Is there a way to capture Browser > Dev tool> Console > "Navigated To" value realtime in an external location without accessing the web app code?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, frontend, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to print Navigated to value real time in an external file. I know that i could have used console.log() in apps js, but I do not have access to web app's code. Basically I am trying to print browser console output to an external log file real time. Then I can parse it to filter on desired variables. I am trying to enable it real time for all the browsers sessions/tabs simultaneously in a single file. Is it possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You asked **I am trying to enable it real time for all the browsers sessions/tabs simultaneously in a single file. Is it possible to achieve?**

There is no tool that can save the console.log in real-time for all the installed browsers on the machine.

The new MS Edge (Chromium) browser, Google Chrome, and Firefox browser now come with an option to save the console data in a file by right-clicking the mouse button-> SaveAs on the log.

The IE browser and MS Edge legacy browser does not have any inbuilt UI option to save the console log in a file.

For the Chromium browsers, you can refer to [this](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging) documentation.

In my search result, I found this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173823/10309381) could be helpful to you.