# Is it possible to log errors with angularjs in file?

Tags: angularjs, logging

Is it possible to log errors with angularjs alone or is it possible to log browser console errors?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Console logs can be downloaded as a file through the browser dev tools. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31059700/4028303