# How to save the output of a console.log(object) to a file?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I tried using `JSON.stringify(object)`, but it doesn't go down on the whole structure and hierarchy.

On the other hand `console.log(object)` does that but I cannot save it.

In the `console.log` output I can expand one by one all the children and select and copy/paste but the structure is to big for that.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462648/export-javascript-console-log-from-google-chrome

Comment: Are you trying to save the console.log from the browser for development purposes? It might help if you explained what your end goal is.

Comment: @MichaelS I didn't find the object in the log file.

Comment: @travis I want to export an object to JSON, but all the hierarchy, also his properties and the properties of his properties. I want practically to get the "interface" of an object  except the implementation of the functions.

Comment: @MichaelS, those questions are about saving the entire log, this question is about saving a single object. They are distinct from my point of view.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462648/export-javascript-console-log-from-google-chrome or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file

Comment: A lot of good answers but why not just use JSON.stringify(your_variable) ? Then take the contents via copy and paste (remove outer quotes).

Comment: For issues about *"**Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**"*, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032565/how-to-copy-the-objects-from-chrome-console-window) could help.

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Update:
[You can now just right click](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+UmarHansa/posts/G3VZ9sG9SCH)

> Right click > Save as in the Console panel to save the logged messages to a file.

Original Answer:

You can use this devtools snippet shown below to create a console.save method. It creates a FileBlob from the input, and then automatically downloads it.

```
(function(console){

console.save = function(data, filename){

    if(!data) {
        console.error('Console.save: No data')
        return;
    }

    if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

    if(typeof data === "object"){
        data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
    }

    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
        e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
        a    = document.createElement('a')

    a.download = filename
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
    e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    a.dispatchEvent(e)
 }
})(console)
```

Source: http://bgrins.github.io/devtools-snippets/#console-save

Comment: I'm not from those who drop "Thanks" everywhere until the answer is blocked to prevent from 'thanks'. But thanks. Gonna build an extension.

Comment: The Save as... feature actually didn't help. It doesn't save the full JSON object (in my case, I had an array of objects, the objects properties weren't exported in the output file). But hopefully, the good old devtool-snippet you pasted worked like a charm. Thank you

Comment: if save as didnt work, then it is a regression. you should file a bug at crbug.com

Comment: great! I was missing the the square brackets around the data parameter in:
`var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'})`

Comment: Doesn't work. I get ```download console:1 undefined``` where 'download console' is the name of the snippet

Comment: @ishandutta2007 you shouldnt be downloading any snippet - it is built into the console now.

Comment: @patrick ignore my comment. I didn't know how to run devtools snippet. I was assuming it will automatically run with page load.

Comment: Right click will not perform a deep save of the object.

Comment: 'Save as' only saves the console to a log file, it won't reveal the property values of the object you console.logged which obviously is what is asked for. This should not be considered the answer,

Comment: This doesn't really work it just saves what you see in the console verbatim. For larger objects usually this is just a bunch of ellipses...

Comment: also link is broken

Comment: Right click on the json data part and save it as global variable then right click on the global variable data in the console and copy-paste it.

Comment: @seyedrezafar your hint helped me save the `navigator` var value to a console log dump file (not json but still useful).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me scrape my ChatGPT conversations.

Answer (score 320):

UPDATE (06/2021):

Google added a menu action to copy objects. Right click on the object and then click `Copy object`

[image]

OLD ANSWER:

In case you have an object logged:

- Right click on the object in console and click `Store as a global variable`
- the output will be something like `temp1`
- type in console `copy(temp1)`
- paste to your favorite text editor

Comment: I also found that pasting this into https://konklone.io/json/ you can then quickly get this into a CSV file and from there into Excel.

Comment: I only get [object Object]

Comment: The console says "undefined", but that does not mean if failed. It still copies it to the clipboard:)

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me, but maybe it should be mentioned that the specific context has to be specified (e.g. when using iFrames)

Comment: The console returns undefined because the copy method doesn't have a return :)

Comment: By far the simplest and most reliable solution!

Comment: thank you! definitely best solution as approved google+ url is dead

Comment: Are the first two steps still necessary? I could just do 'copy(this.myVariable)'.

Answer (score 142):

You can use the [Chrome DevTools Utilities API `copy()` command](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#copyobject) for copying the string representation of the specified object to the clipboard.

If you have lots of objects then you can actually JSON.stringify() all your objects and keep on appending them to a string. Now use `copy()` method to copy the complete string to clipboard.

Comment: Note: **you can use `require("util").format(...)`** instead of applying `JSON.stringify()` one by one. [The `util` module on NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/util) works on both Node.js and web browsers.

Comment: If you type copy(object) and it returned 'undefined', that is actually success. The object is now in your clipboard, and can be pasted.

Answer (score 8):

There is an open-source javascript plugin that does just that - [debugout.js](https://github.com/inorganik/debugout.js)

Debugout.js records and save console.logs so your application can access them. Full disclosure, I wrote it. It formats different types appropriately, can handle nested objects and arrays, and can optionally put a timestamp next to each log. It also toggles live-logging in one place.

Comment: I'm getting an error - `SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module --> debugout.js:9`

Comment: @SenuraDissanayake try now - i had to revert someone's PR that I didn't test :/

Answer (score 5):

This is really late to the party, but maybe it will help someone. My solution seems similar to what the OP described as problematic, but maybe it's a feature that Chrome offers now, but not then.
I tried right-clicking and saving the .log file after the object was written to the console, but all that gave me was a text file with this:

> console.js:230 Done:  Array(50000)[0 … 9999][10000 … 19999][20000 …
>   29999][30000 … 39999][40000 … 49999]length: 50000__proto__: Array(0)

which was of no use to anyone.

What I ended up doing was finding the `console.log(data)` in the code, dropped a breakpoint on it and then typed `JSON.Stringify(data)` in the console which displayed the entire object as a JSON string and the Chrome console actually **gives you a button to copy it**. Then paste into a text editor and there's your JSON

[image]

Comment: it says at the end _long text was truncated_, if your press **Copy** does it copy the entire 20.6MB?

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu yes, everything

Answer (score 3):

There is another open-source tool that allows you to save all `console.log` output in a file on your server - [JS LogFlush](https://github.com/hindmost/jslogflush) (plug!).

> ***JS LogFlush*** is an integrated JavaScript logging solution which include:
>
> - cross-browser UI-less replacement of console.log - on client side.
> - log storage system - on server side.

[Demo](http://youtu.be/AFfTu2F3leM)

Answer (score 2):

You can use library `l2i` (https://github.com/seriyvolk83/logs2indexeddb) to save all you put into `console.log`
and then invoke

```
l2i.download();
```

to download a file with logs.

Answer (score 2):

right click on console.. click save as.. its this simple.. you'll get an output text file

Comment: just without any indication of what is error vs waning vs log.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on object and saving was not available for me.

**The working solution for me is given below**

Log as pretty string shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7220510/7765316)

```
console.log('jsonListBeauty', JSON.stringify(jsonList, null, 2));
```

in Chrome DevTools, Log shows as below

[image: saveJsonlog]

Just press Copy, It will be copied to clipboard with desired spacing level

Paste it on your favorite text editor and save it

---

> image took on 15/02/2021, Google Chrome Version 88.0.4324.150

Answer (score 0):

A more simple way is to use fire fox dev tools, console.log(yourObject) -> right click on object -> select "copy object" -> paste results into notepad

thanks.

Comment: This option already appears to have been covered by the accepted answer already. Also, the question is tagged for Google Chrome.