# How to save console log from chrome in local file without any third party tool?

Tags: google-chrome, embedded-linux, chromium

It look like duplicate of this [Save the console.log in Chrome to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file) ,but Accepted answer doesn't seem to work anymore and rest are third party plugin. Also question is very old. Asking for any update.

I tried using above solution, but console-debug log doesn't print console.log

I am using chromium 40 on IMX6Q Board with Linux and not allowed to install any extension.

Comment: [I just confirmed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file#comment50248919_10068090) the linked answer does indeed work.  I ran chrome v43 with `--enable-logging --v=1` on OSX 10.10.3 and my console output does get saved to chrome_debug.log

Comment: Might be this link can help you..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849562/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-console-logobject-to-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is native support to do this. Right click console area and choose "Save as". [image]

Tested with Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 m