# How to copy the objects from chrome console window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-console

I have tried to copy the objects as text, but it show just [object object]. Before this I had tried with **copy** commend it was success but not now.Is that chrome issue?

**What I tried?**
Just Right click on the object and store as global variable from chrome console window, then next just used copy(temp6) command and tried to paste in notepad++.

[image]

Comment: FYI I'm also experiencing this issue.  In my limited testing though, it seems that the issue is present when I try to copy an object with a method defined.  If I remove the method, then issue is gone.  I know that's not a solution, but it maybe helps others figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 71):

It should ideally copy the object with the `copy` command that you wrote.
I just tried it and worked for me.

Something else that you can try to do is to stringify that object and then copy it.
Ex.

```
copy(JSON.stringify(temp6))
```

Comment: It shows **Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**

Comment: @Jay How does that help? Is the user supposed to write a custom JSON function into their devTools every time they want to stringify an object?

Comment: You can right mouse click an object and store it as a global variable. it will most likely be called "temp1", afterwards you can use the code snippet as follows: JSON.stringify(temp1). Hope this clarifies it a bit.

Comment: It shows the "circular structure" warning because your object has cycles, which makes it impossible to serialize to JSON. For example object A has property pointing to object B, and B has a property pointing back to A.

Answer (score 53):

If the object already logged

- Right-click on the object in console and click Store as a global
- variable the output will be something like temp1
- Copy and paste below code in chrome console and hit enter

  ```
  (function(console){
      console.save = function(data, filename){

      if(!data) {
          console.error('Console.save: No data')
          return;
      }

      if(!filename) filename = 'console.json'

      if(typeof data === "object"){
          data = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 4)
      }

      var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/json'}),
          e    = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'),
          a    = document.createElement('a')

      a.download = filename
      a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      a.dataset.downloadurl =  ['text/json', a.download, a.href].join(':')
      e.initMouseEvent('click', true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
      a.dispatchEvent(e)
   }
  })(console)
  ```

  - Then you can use the function for downloading,

console.save(temp1);

-If it shows **Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**

then you need decycle JSON object and paste below code in chrome browser console and hit enter

```
if (typeof JSON.decycle !== "function") {
    JSON.decycle = function decycle(object, replacer) {
        "use strict";

        var objects = new WeakMap();     // object to path mappings

        return (function derez(value, path) {


            var old_path;  
            var nu;  

            if (replacer !== undefined) {
                value = replacer(value);
            }

            if (
                typeof value === "object" && value !== null &&
                !(value instanceof Boolean) &&
                !(value instanceof Date) &&
                !(value instanceof Number) &&
                !(value instanceof RegExp) &&
                !(value instanceof String)
            ) {


                old_path = objects.get(value);
                if (old_path !== undefined) {
                    return {$ref: old_path};
                }

                objects.set(value, path);

                if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                    nu = [];
                    value.forEach(function (element, i) {
                        nu[i] = derez(element, path + "[" + i + "]");
                    });
                } else {

                    nu = {};
                    Object.keys(value).forEach(function (name) {
                        nu[name] = derez(
                            value[name],
                            path + "[" + JSON.stringify(name) + "]"
                        );
                    });
                }
                return nu;
            }
            return value;
        }(object, "$"));
    };
}


if (typeof JSON.retrocycle !== "function") {
    JSON.retrocycle = function retrocycle($) {
        "use strict";

        var px = /^\$(?:\[(?:\d+|"(?:[^\\"\u0000-\u001f]|\\([\\"\/bfnrt]|u[0-9a-zA-Z]{4}))*")\])*$/;

        (function rez(value) {



            if (value && typeof value === "object") {
                if (Array.isArray(value)) {
                    value.forEach(function (element, i) {
                        if (typeof element === "object" && element !== null) {
                            var path = element.$ref;
                            if (typeof path === "string" && px.test(path)) {
                                value[i] = eval(path);
                            } else {
                                rez(element);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Object.keys(value).forEach(function (name) {
                        var item = value[name];
                        if (typeof item === "object" && item !== null) {
                            var path = item.$ref;
                            if (typeof path === "string" && px.test(path)) {
                                value[name] = eval(path);
                            } else {
                                rez(item);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }($));
        return $;
    };
}
```

- Then finally execute code for downloading.

`console.save(JSON.decycle(temp1));`

Comment: actually, objects are not copying correctly, only the [0] is correct the rest are not

Comment: It's worked for me, thanks so much. Oh, after all, instead of using save, you can use copy(JSON.decycle(temp1)) to save temp1 to clipboard

Comment: Commenting to 'favourite' this answer for later due to lack of feature. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite-star

Comment: console.save(temp1); worked for me , i dint find the need to decycle it. Thanks for your snippet this saved time

Comment: Legend! :heart:

Comment: Thank you, was stuck on this for a while.

Answer (score 10):

You can use command in console as follows:
Let say our object is:

```
  var object = {x:"xyz"}
```

Now use below command in console -

```
 copy(JSON.stringify(object))
```

object is now available to clipboard.You can now use Ctrl + v to use this object.

Comment: It shows **Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**

Answer (score 5):

You should check the`count` object to avoid circular reference, before using `copy(JSON.stringify(count))`, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616630/json-stringify-avoid-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json)

Comment: @5tormTrooper DevTools has built-in JSON function

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this without having to write any code. At least with later version of chrome.

When you right click the object you get this context:
[image]

But if you left click the line to highlight it, the right click the console line you get this context menu:
[image]

The "Save as..." option will create text file (*.log) of everything "as is" currently on the console log. So if you want to see more of the object simply expand it as far as you need.

collapsed example:

```
let tmpArr = []; tmpArr.push([]); tmpArr[0].push({ some: 'test'}); tmpArr[0].push({ some: 'next'}); console.log(tmpArr);
VM242:1 [Array(2)]0: (2) [{…}, {…}]length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
undefined
null
null
```

expanded example:

```
let tmpArr = []; tmpArr.push([]); tmpArr[0].push({ some: 'test'}); tmpArr[0].push({ some: 'next'}); console.log(tmpArr);
VM242:1 [Array(2)]0: Array(2)0: some: "test"[[Prototype]]: Object1: some: "next"[[Prototype]]: Objectlength: 2[[Prototype]]: Array(0)length: 1[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
undefined
null
null
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in 2021+ @Merbin Jo!

Answer (score 2):

there can be many ways to do this. One way could be to do `JSON.stringify(yourObject)` and then copy the output.

Comment: It shows **Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**

Comment: that explains why `copy` wasn't working in the first place. There is an explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816099/chrome-sendrequest-error-typeerror-converting-circular-structure-to-json#4816258)