# Replicate chrome web developer console with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Firstly apologies - my knowledge is really in server side PHP programming but I have been thrown in at the deep end with a request and would really like to just know if this is possible.

We have a testing framework which requires various things to be checked in the web developer console but this is something which happens over multiple pages and multiple brands and currently the tests are done manually.

Is there any way to access console items by using a javascript (or other language) that can check certain criteria seen in the console and output the results in a csv format for comparisons to be made?
For example, using the network tab we would want to check on the status of an element.

Please note, I'm not asking for help on coding this, just understanding if this can be done and with which resources.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this out 
[Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools)

Comment: Seems weird you would need to check the console. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849562/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-console-logobject-to-a-file

Comment: Thanks Dalorzo - will check that out!
Thanks for the link epascarello - we need to check on things such as making sure correct variables are being parsed in tracking urls, checking if js variables are set etc - it's essentially a check to make sure that nothing has been broken or changed.

Comment: What do you mean by "console items"? Do you mean the Console output? Or the output of calls like `console.log()`, `console.warn()`, etc.