# How to export data, e.g. from console.log() from a Chrome extension to Python script

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension

I have written a Chrome extension that periodically currently outputs the scraped data to the console log.
I want to get this data into a Python script to manipulate and graph it, as I am too unfamiliar with JS to do so within a the extension.

I don't mind how it gets into a Python script, but it should preferably be in a way that is easy to update frequently.

I apologise for my lack of JS knowledge. :)

Comment: The data can easily be stored as text, so having that transferred would be suitable.

Comment: Save the console log to a file, then parse with Python script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849562/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-console-logobject-to-a-file

Comment: Create a web service and communicate with it.