# how to copy json output on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using below plugin to show  json .

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-json-view.

can we have a button to which will copy this json.

https://codesandbox.io/s/async-pine-o6eho

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          alert("---");
        }}
      >
        Copy
      </button>
      <ReactJson src={my_json_object} theme="monokai" />
    </div>
  );
```

can we copy the below json output on button click?

Comment: Where is the "below json"? And what do you mean "copy"?

Comment: if you open `conpen` .it will show `json viewer`

Comment: @copy means  `on button` click it will copy this value and paste in notpad

Comment: Your problem solution is here, please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849562/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-console-logobject-to-a-file thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your JSON by setting content of it to a temporary input and using `document.execCommand('copy')`.

```
function Copy(json) {
    const input = document.createElement("textarea");
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.value = JSON.stringify(json);
    input.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(input);
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-smoke-wo39c) is a working example based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
onClick={() => {

  let objCopy = Object.assign({}, my_json_object);
  alert(JSON.stringify(objCopy));
}}
```