# Save console.log output into a file

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript code that is printing a few statements that I would like to save in a file, which I will parse with a Python code.

I have saw multiple solutions, but I am having a hard time to modifying my code to save the `console.log` output.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
import { JSBI } from "@uniswap/sdk";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import * as fs from 'fs';

    // ERC20 json abi file
let ERC20Abi = fs.readFileSync('ERC20.json');
const ERC20 = JSON.parse(ERC20Abi);

    // V3 pool abi json file
let pool = fs.readFileSync('V3PairAbi.json');
const IUniswapV3PoolABI = JSON.parse(pool);

    // V3 factory abi json
let facto = fs.readFileSync('V3factory.json');
const IUniswapV3FactoryABI = JSON.parse(facto);

let NFT = fs.readFileSync('UniV3NFT.json');
const IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI = JSON.parse(NFT);

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(ALCHEMY)

    // V3 standard addresses (different for celo)
const factory = FACTORY;
const NFTmanager = NFTMANAGER;

async function getData(tokenID){
    let FactoryContract = new ethers.Contract(factory, IUniswapV3FactoryABI, provider);

    let NFTContract =  new ethers.Contract(NFTmanager, IUniswapV3NFTmanagerABI, provider);
    let position = await NFTContract.positions(tokenID);
    
    let token0contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token0, ERC20, provider);
    let token1contract =  new ethers.Contract(position.token1, ERC20, provider);
    let token0Decimal = await token0contract.decimals();
    let token1Decimal = await token1contract.decimals();
    
    let token0sym = await token0contract.symbol();
    let token1sym = await token1contract.symbol();
    
    let V3pool = await FactoryContract.getPool(position.token0, position.token1, position.fee);
    let poolContract = new ethers.Contract(V3pool, IUniswapV3PoolABI, provider);

    let slot0 = await poolContract.slot0();

    
    let pairName = token0sym +"/"+ token1sym;
    
    let dict = {"SqrtX96" : slot0.sqrtPriceX96.toString(), "Pair": pairName, "T0d": token0Decimal, "T1d": token1Decimal, "tickLow": position.tickLower, "tickHigh": position.tickUpper, "liquidity": position.liquidity.toString()}

    return dict
}


const Q96 = JSBI.exponentiate(JSBI.BigInt(2), JSBI.BigInt(96));
const MIN_TICK = -887272;
const MAX_TICK = 887272;

function getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96){
    let tick = Math.floor(Math.log((sqrtPriceX96/Q96)**2)/Math.log(1.0001));
    return tick;
}

async function getTokenAmounts(liquidity,sqrtPriceX96,tickLow,tickHigh,token0Decimal,token1Decimal){
    let sqrtRatioA = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickLow).toFixed(18);
    let sqrtRatioB = Math.sqrt(1.0001**tickHigh).toFixed(18);
    let currentTick = getTickAtSqrtRatio(sqrtPriceX96);
    let sqrtPrice = sqrtPriceX96 / Q96;
    let amount0wei = 0;
    let amount1wei = 0;
    if(currentTick <= tickLow){
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA)/(sqrtRatioA*sqrtRatioB)));
    }
    if(currentTick > tickHigh){
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtRatioB-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    if(currentTick >= tickLow && currentTick < tickHigh){ 
        amount0wei = Math.floor(liquidity*((sqrtRatioB-sqrtPrice)/(sqrtPrice*sqrtRatioB)));
        amount1wei = Math.floor(liquidity*(sqrtPrice-sqrtRatioA));
    }
    
    let amount0Human = (amount0wei/(10**token0Decimal)).toFixed(token0Decimal);
    let amount1Human = (amount1wei/(10**token1Decimal)).toFixed(token1Decimal);

    console.log("Amount Token0 wei: "+amount0wei);
    console.log("Amount Token1 wei: "+amount1wei);
    console.log("Amount Token0 : "+amount0Human);
    console.log("Amount Token1 : "+amount1Human);
    return [amount0wei, amount1wei]
}

async function start(positionID){
    let data = await getData(positionID);
    let tokens = await getTokenAmounts(data.liquidity, data.SqrtX96, data.tickLow, data.tickHigh, data.T0d, data.T1d);
}

start(POOLID)
// Also it can be used without the position data if you pull the data it will work for any range
getTokenAmounts(12558033400096537032, 20259533801624375790673555415)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849562/how-to-save-the-output-of-a-console-logobject-to-a-file

Comment: Start logging using [JSON lines](https://jsonlines.org/) now (one JSON value per line) and you'll save yourself a lot of parsing trouble later.

Comment: Thank you both for the tips/links. I am having a bit of trouble with adding this to the code to help me save the logs to a file on my computer. Any idea how I can modify the code above to help me achieve this?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74513674/save-console-log-output-into-a-file#comment131535036_74513674) @beeeZeee You can write your own logger or just use something like [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston), [pino](https://github.com/pinojs/pino), etc. "How to write logging software?" is out of scope for a Stack Overflow question.