# JQuery console log to file

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a good jQuery plugin that will log console errors to a file so I can track any errors users are experiencing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4309958/561731

Comment: Hi, not really as thats asking to save one users console.log to a file. Im want a plugin / script that sits on the server and runs everytime anyone loads the page, if an error should occur it logs it to a file. I can then view this file after a short while to see any errors.

Comment: Forgive me, the answer to the post above is of no use to your situation, as it would require effort on the part of your users. This  one should help you though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462648/export-javascript-console-log-from-google-chrome "I want a jQuery plugin" is not really the type of question for this place though, although it would be a good idea for one. You should build it!

Comment: Sigh. I wish people would read more carefully when closing as a duplicate. :[ But yeah, very likely reopening this would just get it closed again as not constructive, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only option is to put in place a function that would AJAX the info to your server, where you would then write it to a file on your local server.  jQuery itself won't magically write files to your server.

Comment: Removed that part, I was referring to general web errors.  But how does writing to the clients computer help him read JS errors?  Are they supposed to email the files to him?

Comment: Well I found a good script that does front-end js logging:https://github.com/remybach/jQuery.clientSideLogging